# Angular How to Display content outside of application root

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display some content, something like a 'div' outside of the application root, inside the body tag of the root html.

Is it possible in Angular?

For example see this Angular Hello world app when we inspect the html we see "Hello Angular 4" content inside `<hello>` tag:

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jsrf.png)

I need to display "Hello Angular 4" outside `<my-app>` as below
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T3Dg.png)

Comment: You can add it to the `index.html` file, though it'll need to be just static HTML, i.e. no Angular bits

Comment: You can use every DOM manipulations like `document.body.appendChild`. Use the Document Angular Provider instead of direct access to document if you plan to use SSR

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948763/bootstrap-two-apps-in-same-page-using-angular-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link:-  https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-kaa5u8?file=src%2Findex.html

### index.html

```
<head>
<script src="..///" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var h = document.createElement("H4");
var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World2");
h.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(h);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<my-app>loading</my-app>
<h4>hello boy</h4>
</body>
```

or

### app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
       var h = document.createElement("H1");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
    h.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(h);
  }
```

In angular2+ , there is just a `body` tag which holds root component ie `<app-root></app-root>`  which contains views(templates) and typescript files(as business logic controller). If you want to just write something out of root component, you can directly add relevant codes inside  `body`  tag. Same goes for script files as well.